# Socket.io when client Internet going to off

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

How can i callback from client to server internet going to off? I have users and i added their connections in the some room. But I can not know when they are Internet going to down. I want to callback their statues but I do not know how. My clients are android phone.

this function does not work.

```
socket.on("disconnect", function () {
    var SocketRoom= socket.room;
    socket.leave(SocketRoom);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clients can't send a message through the socket connection, if they are not connected to the network/internet anymore. You might want to check for timeouts.

Once a client connects to the server, the server sends a message to the client in a fixed time interval (like every 5 seconds).
If the client responds to that message, you know, it's still conencted and continue with your program logic.
If the client does not respond to your message, then they are very likely not connected to the internet anymore (or are unreachable for other reasons). If this is the case, you can force them to leave the room (like in your `socket.on("disconnect", ...)` function).

Please note:

- The higher the timeout interval, the less precise is the actual disconnect time, but the load on the connection is kept low.
- If a client does not respond to a timeout-check, you might want to retry to send a message to that client a couple of times before force-closing the connection.

Comment: Okay Thats fine. But.... I need  sesivity result about learn connection. If i send every 0.1-0.5 sec my server is working bad think I have a lot of connection. How can i send them signal ? If i use this way my server answer me too late right ? There is not any way for it ? I am using it now but i need a idea better than your idea. But you are right. If i send a some signal from server to client and the client do not answer me the conenction is false right...

Comment: No, it's not possible, as far as i know. You can't send any messages to the server, if you lost your internet connection. ;)
You can increase the timeout though, 1-2 sec are fine in most cases.

Comment: Okay i am using this way now :) Just ask for it . I think there is a way for it :D :) But we will see.. Because the signal is raping my server you know :)

Comment: Well, you could let the clients send a message to the server, and then you check every 5 seconds on the server, if a client hasn't answered since the last check and kick it. But basicly, it's the same just vice versa.